# Objektposition im Fragesatz

Tags: sentence-structure, word-order, question

Ich bin vor Kurzem gefragt worden, warum in den folgenden Fragesätzen das Objekt seine Position wechseln kann:

1. > Kann mir jemand mit den Matheaufgaben helfen?
2. > Kann jemand mir mit den Matheaufgaben helfen?

In (1) haben wir Verb-Objekt-Subjekt-…
In (2) haben wir Verb-Subjekt-Objekt-…

In den folgenden Fragesätzen kann das Objekt seine Position aber nicht wechseln:

3. > Kannst Du mir mit den Matheaufgaben helfen?
4. > *Kannst mir Du mit den Matheaufgaben helfen?

Ich hab im topologischen Feldermodell herumgesucht, aber keine Antwort gefunden. Hat irgendjemand eine Idee, wie man erklären kann, dass (1), (2) und (3) grammatisch sind, (4) aber nicht?

Comment: Die Antwort ist klar: (4) ist genauso grammatisch. Übrigens willkommen auf dem Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen, und wenn du Fragen hast, wie sie funktioniert, schaue im [help] nach.

Comment: In meinen Ohren ist zwischen 2 und 4 kein Unterschied. Beides hört sich schrecklich an. Beides ist nicht verboten, gehört trotzdem imho in einer Deutschklausur angekreidet.

Comment: Und nun meine Einschätzung: 4 ist hart an der Grenze, aber gerade noch grammatisch. 2 ist OK, aber etwas weniger üblich als 1.

Answer (score 4):

Alle vier Fälle ergeben grammatikalisch korrekte Sätze. Das ist ja gerade das Schöne am Deutschen, dass fast jede Kombination möglich ist, solange die richtige Verbstellung beachtet wird. Auch die vier Varianten, die du nicht explizit aufgelistet hast, sind möglich und nicht falsch:

> Kann mit den Matheaufgaben jemand mir helfen?
>   Kann mit den Matheaufgaben mir jemand helfen?
>   Kannst mit den Matheaufgaben du mir helfen?
>   Kannst mit den Matheaufgaben mir du helfen?

»Nicht falsch« heißt aber nicht automatisch »schön«. Ganz im Gegenteil, gerade bei den letzten beiden Beispielen stellen sich einem die Nackenhaare auf. Dass liegt daran, dass diese Sätze eine große Spannung transportieren.

Spannung ist ein interessantes Feld, wenn man Sätze zusammenbaut. Normalerweise verwenden wir sie zur Betonung von Satzfragmenten – deswegen steht in diesem Satz das *normalerweise* vorne, obwohl die »natürliche« Ordnung eine andere wäre. Einige Regeln um Spannung zu reduzieren sind:

- Bekanntes vor Unbekanntem
- Kurz vor Lang
- Subjekt vor Objekt
- Thema vor Rhema
- … und viele mehr

In deiner ersten Beispielfrage beißen sich die Regeln ein wenig gegenseitig. »Bekanntes vor Unbekanntem«, »Kurz vor Lang« und »Thema vor Rhema« verlangen, dass *mir* vor *jemand* steht. »Subjekt vor Objekt« möchte das *jemand* gerne vor ziehen. »Kurz vor Lang« ist damit fast einverstanden (*jemand* ist schließlich auch ziemlich kurz, wenngleich *mir* kürzer ist). Insgesamt bedeutet das, dass keiner der beiden Sätze völlig spannungsfrei ist, aber beide auch nur sehr geringe Spannung in sich tragen.

In deiner zweiten Beispielfrage sind sich die Regeln relativ einig. Alle vier verlangen, dass *du* vor *mir* gestellt wird, deswegen klingt »Kannst du mir …« auch so natürlich. »Kurz vor Lang« erklärt sich noch damit einverstanden, wenn die Reihenfolge getauscht wird, und »Thema vor Rhema« interessiert sich mehr für die Matheaufgaben. Beide Glieder sind aber schon bekannt (das *du* wird durch die konjugierte Verbform vorweggenommen), weswegen »Subjekt vor Objekt« stärker zu wirken scheint.

Im Fall der vorgezogenen Matheaufgaben ist ganz klar, dass das gegen »Thema vor Rhema«, »Bekanntes vor Unbekanntem« und gegen »Kurz vor Lang« verstößt, abgesehen davon, dass »Subjekt vor Objekt« gerne mindestens eines seiner Glieder an den Anfang stellen würde. Das erklärt die sehr hohe Spannung in diesen Sätzen, die noch verstärkt wird, wenn sogar das *du* durch seine Verbform vorweggenommen wird, wie in meinen unteren Beispielen. Dennoch sind, nur um das nochmal zu betonen, *alle Varianten grammatikalisch korrekt.*

Dein Sprachempfinden wie auch Em1s und chirlus Kommentare deuten allerdings richtig an, dass in einer Schulaufgabe die spannungsreichen Varianten als *Ausdrucksfehler* angekreidet gehören.

Comment: Schöne Antwort. Wenn's um Grammatik des Standarddeutschen geht, differieren sich Meinungen eines Bayers und eines Kölners nicht ;)